# SASS: "Autosave" imports of partials?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

Novice web dev here getting set up with SASS for the first time. Currently using Grunt to compile my css from a main SASS file.

So I have three files:

```
//main.css
/*some css*/

//main.scss
@import 'header';

//_header.scss
/* some sass */
```

When I edit and save the `_header.scss` file, I also have to save the `main.scss` file. Only then will gulp compile changes in the `main.css` file.

Is there a way to "autosave" every file that contains an import of a partial?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what your providing I am thinking it has something to do with your main.css stuff at the top of your file. I am assuming that you have actual css below that comment in the real file?

Best practice is to @import everything at the top of the file before you do anything else.

If that is exactly what you have in the real file then it might be with how your running grunt.. Would you be able to provide your grunt config file please?